# Static and Dynamic Scoping Problem

Tags: programming-languages, pseudocode

I'm solving following code in Static and Dynamic Scoping.
I got following answer but I need someone to confirm if I'm correct or not since I'm a bit confusing. I really appreciate if anyone can explain in simple way!

```
Static  => (1)8  (2)27
Dynamic => (1)10 (2)27

proc main
var x,y,z;
    proc sub1
        var x,z
        x := 6;
        z := 7;
        sub2;
        x := y*z + x;
        print(x);   ---- (2)
    end;
    proc sub2
        var x,y
        x := 1;
        y := x+z+2;
        print(y);   ---- (1)
    end;
begin
    x := 1; y:=3; z:=5;
    sub1;
end
```

Comment: This code doesn't really look like pascal, is it pseudo code?

Comment: Scooping is not what you think it is...

Comment: You probably also mean lexical scoping instead of static scoping.

Answer (score 5):

Scoping defines the rules by which the variable identifiers in your code (i.e. names) are mapped to the actual variables.

Static (or lexical) scoping determines the mapping, by which variable names are mapped based on the program code structure. First the immediate scope (i.e. the block between `proc`..`end` in your pseudo-language), that is the scope where the variable is referenced, is searched for the variable declaration. If it's there, the name is bound to this variable. If it's not, the name is looked up in the parent scope (based on the code structure - i.e. on the program text), in the grandparent, etc.

In your case, in `sub2`, in the expression `x+z+2`, x always refers to the local variable (defined in the same scope), z always refers to the variable defined in the `main` proc - this mapping does not depend on the actual program execution. Therefore, with static scoping, `x` refers to local variable with value of `1`, `z` refers to the variable in `main` with the value of `5`, so the result is `5+1+2=8`. Note that in `sub1`, `x` and `z` are local variables - i.e. `z := 7` does not change the `z` in `main`.

Dynamic scoping is like the static scoping in that it first looks for the variable in the immediate scope, and then continues to look in the scope ancestors. However, while with static scoping the scope hierarchy is determined by program text, with dynamic scoping the hierarchy is determined by the hierarchy of subroutine calls your program makes - i.e. scope hierarchy and callstack are alike.

With dynamic scoping, at the point `(1)`, the callstack is as follows: `main -> sub1 -> sub2`. Thus the names in `sub2` are first looked up in `sub2` (the `x` name resolves to `x` local variable, as with static scoping), then in `sub1` (the `z` name resolves to the `z` variable in `sub1`), then in `main`.

So `x` resolves to the variable with value `1`, `z` resolves to the variable from `sub2` with the value `7`, and the result is `10`. Finally, the `y` in `sub2` is looked in `sub2`, then in `main` (because the call stack is `main -> sub2`), so the expression result at `(2)` is `3*7+6=27` - this is the same as with static scoping because the static (lexical) scope hierarchy and the dynamic (call-based) hierarchy are equal at this point of execution.